# Как вызвать непереопределенную версию метода внутри родительского класса?

Tags: java

Можно ли переделать в классе "А" метод "function1" так, чтобы получить вывод "AA"?

```
package javatest;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new B().function1();
    }
}

class A {
    public void function1() {
        System.out.println("A");
        function2();
    }
    protected void function2() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void function1() {
        super.function1();
    }
    public void function2() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

На PHP это можно было бы написать так:

```
class A {
    public function function1() {
        echo("A");
        self::function2();
    }
    protected function function2() {
        echo("A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function function1() {
        parent::function1();
    }
    public function function2() {
        echo("B");
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->function1();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Java так сделать не получится, т.к. все методы виртуальны и, насколько мне известно, нет синтаксического сахара для обращения к конкретной реализации.

Соответственно, если вызывается метод с модификатором `protected`, то ожидается, что поведение этого метода может быть переопределено наследниками. В этом весь смысл виртуальных методов.

Для того чтобы внутреннее поведение метода нельзя было переопределить в наследниках, можно использовать методы private, которые наследникам недоступны.

Например, так:

```
class A {
    public void function1() {
        System.out.println("A");
        function3();
    }
    protected void function2() {
        function3();
    }

    private void function3() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

Т.о. общий код `function1` и `function2` вынесен в отдельный метод `function3`. При этом классы-наследники могут переопределить поведение `function2` без вреда для `function1`.

Answer (score -3):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно вывести "AA" в одну строку? Если так, то используйте "print" вместо "println"

Comment: Боюсь что Вы неправильно поняли вопрос. Текущий код в вопросе выводит `AB`, автор хочет вывести `AA`